# Remove Unused ViewControllers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, three20

When I click in the TTTabBar, the tabs elected sends me to one the the correct ViewController, then I click another TTTabBar it will send me to the other one.....etc, but how can I remove the last ViewController, so they don't just keep stacking on top of each other.

```
- (void)tabBar:(TTTabBar*)tabBar tabSelected:(NSInteger)selectedIndex
{       
if(selectedIndex == 0){
    UIViewController* viewController = (UIViewController*)[[TTNavigator navigator] viewControllerForURL:@"tt://Forum"];
    [self.view addSubview:viewController.view];
    [self.view addSubview:_tabBar];
}else if(selectedIndex == 1) {
    UIViewController* viewController = (UIViewController*)[[TTNavigator navigator] viewControllerForURL:@"tt://Profile"];
    [self.view addSubview:viewController.view];
    [self.view addSubview:_tabBar];
}else if(selectedIndex == 2) {
    UIViewController* viewController = (UIViewController*)[[TTNavigator navigator] viewControllerForURL:@"tt://PMs"];
    [self.view addSubview:viewController.view];
    [self.view addSubview:_tabBar];
}else if(selectedIndex == 3) {
    UIViewController* viewController = (UIViewController*)[[TTNavigator navigator] viewControllerForURL:@"tt://Friends"];
    [self.view addSubview:viewController.view];
    [self.view addSubview:_tabBar];
} 
}
```

I got this to work

```
if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[UIViewController class]]) {
    [viewController.view removeFromSuperview];
} else {

}
```

when i added it above

```
    if(selectedIndex == 0){
```

Comment: if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[UIViewController class]]) {
  [viewController.view removeFromSuperview];
 } else {
  
 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
- (void)removeFromSuperview
```

To do that in your scenario you'll have to keep a reference to the current view around or create a way of getting a reference to it using a tag.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html

Answer (score 0):

Is `TTNavigator` a class you wrote? It looks like a singleton manager class to me... Is `viewControllerForUrl` returning an autoreleased instance of `UIViewController`? You could implement a stack in the `TTNavigator` where you would hold the references to all your view controllers and then popping them as you see fit.